# How to refresh the table data in angular 9

Tags: angular8, angular9

Trying to refresh the table data without empty the table data before refresh in angular but it is not working properly. How to resolve this issue.

app.component.html:

```
  <data-table [data]="tableData" [header]="tableHeader"></data-table>
  <button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
refresh(){
         this.loadingicon=true;
         //this.tableData=[]; ->avoiding this
         //this.tableHeader = [];->avoiding this
         this.tableData=[...this.tableData];
         this.tableHeader = [...this.tableHeader];
         if(this.tableData.length != 0){
          this.loadingicon=false;
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ChangeDetectorRef** method for that.

Define in your constructor like

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){ }
```

Use in your refresh function

```
refresh(){
   this.loadingicon=true;
   this.tableData=[...this.tableData];
   this.tableHeader = [...this.tableHeader];
   this.ref.markForCheck(); // use this method or
   this.ref.detectChanges(); // use this method
   if(this.tableData.length != 0){
       this.loadingicon=false;
   }
}
```

Please refer [this](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) link for more details.